# Remote Debugging on GoogleTv

Tags: android, adb, remote-debugging, google-tv

While doing a remote debugging on GoogleTv, I've followed everything mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_hardware_devices
The problem is that I'm able to do remote debugging on a Windows machine, but the same thing is not working on UBUNTU.

On Ubuntu, when I do:

```
adb connect <ip>
```

It shows connected. But when I do:

```
adb devices
```

It shows me nothing. Restarting the adb server has been of no help.

Comment: Did you also set 'adb tcpip 5555', also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: Yes, It says error: device not found.
However, the same thing is working on Windows machine

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of repeating the obvious. What's your Windows ip address? And what's your Ubuntu's workstation ip address?

> In the **Settings** application, select **Applications > Development**.
>
> Set **Remote debugging** to allow your workstation to connect to this device.
>
> Click **Debugger IP address**, then in the dialog enter your workstation's IP address and click **Set**.

Obviously, this must be done **twice** since the ip address of your Windows workstation is going to be slightly different from the ip address of your Ubuntu workstation.

Comment: While connecting with Ubuntu i'm entering Ubuntu's IP address and while connecting to Windows I'm entering Window's - that's not the problem.
Actually on enterting Ubuntu's IP, I am able to connect - if there would have been problem with IP I would not have even been able to connect. The problem is that after successful connection, the GoogleTv Box is undetectable on my Ubuntu machine

Comment: That's very strange. What kind of GoogleTV is it? Have you tried restarting it, or updating it? Personally, I've never had any problem with my Ubuntu laptop and my Logitech GoogleTV.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on windows but not Ubuntu make sure that your Ubuntu machine IP is the one specified on the GTV device development settings. Also check your firewall settings on Ubuntu, if your IP is correct try to disable the firewall and reconnect to your GTV device. If it works then create a custom rule for your firewall.